# SQL Server: Insert into two tables at the same time with FK to each other

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, sql-insert

I need to do an insert on 2 tables where both have a foreign key to each other (non-nullable)
Unfortunately, using transactions does not work. Any other way to do this?

Comment: So table A has a foreign key to table B, and B has a foreign key to A? Sounds like an odd design choice...

Comment: Correct. Apart from the odd design, any idea if this can be done? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Unfortunately, using transactions does not work. Any other way to do this?

The only way to do this in SQL Server is to alter the table to NOCHECK one of the constraints while you insert data (or use bulk insert or replication which can both bypass constraint checking).  Obviously, this is not something you want to do at runtime.

The typical solution is to allow one of the FKs to be nullable.

Comment: I used a transaction to NOCHECK before change and CHECK again afterwards. I agree that this should not be done at runtime. (for me, this is an exceptional case and will only be done once at creation of DB). Thanks!

Comment: Cool.  Running DDL at Deployment-time is not problematic.