# How to post foreign key that’s passed from another action controller as a primary key? (ADO.NET ASP.NET MVC)

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc, stored-procedures, ado.net

I have tables:

- `Shipment` (ssuid, sCompanyName, sFName, sMName, sLName, sAddress1, sAddress2, sCity, sState, sPostalCode, sCountry)
- `Packages` (ppuid, psuid, pTrackingNumber)

where `psuid` is a foreign key (to `ssuid` in the `Shipment` table)

First, the user posts the new shipment data in `AddShipment.cshtml` with the following code:

```
public ActionResult AddShipment()
{
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult AddShipment([FromForm] Shipment shipment)
{
    var fk = Guid.NewGuid();

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectonString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("POST_Shipment", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SSuid", fk);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCompanyName", shipment.SCompanyName);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SFname", shipment.SFname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SMname", shipment.SMname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SLname", shipment.SLname);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAddress1", shipment.SAddress1);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SAddress2", shipment.SAddress2);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCity", shipment.SCity);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SState", shipment.SState);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SPostalCode", shipment.SPostalCode);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SCountry", shipment.SCountry);                    
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SDateEntered", DateTime.Now);    

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("AddPackage", "Package", new { suid = fk}); 
}
```

When the user hits submit button, it will post the shipment data and pass the primary key (`ssuid`) as a foreign key (`psuid`), and direct to the next page (`addPackage.cshtml`).

The user finally enters the package info and submits the form by the following controller:

```
public ActionResult AddPackage(Guid suid)
{
    ViewBag.shipmentId = suid;

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult AddPackage(Guid suid, Package package)
{
    ViewBag.shipmentId = suid;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectonString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("POST_Package", con))
        {
            cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PPuid", Guid.NewGuid());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PSuid", suid);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PTrackingNumber", package.PTrackingNumber);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PDateEntered", DateTime.Now);

            con.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
        }
    }

    return RedirectToAction("AddShipment", "Shipment");
}
```

I also added `psuid` in view page (`AddPackage.cshtml`) by

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.PSuid, new {value = ViewBag.shipmentId})
```

When I finally run the code, I have get an exception:

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'The INSERT statement
> conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Packages_Shipments".
> The conflict occurred in database "Operations", table "dbo.Shipments",
> column 'sSUID'. The statement has been terminated.'

in `AddPackage` POST method.

The `suid` in the `POST` method is empty (`00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000`) while the `suid` in `GET` method is not. What is the correct way to include the foreign key passed from another controller? Thank you in advance for your help.

In case if you want to see my stored procedure (`POST_Package`), this is it:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[POST_Package]
    @PPuid uniqueidentifier,
    @PSuid uniqueidentifier,
    @PTrackingNumber varchar = null,
    @PDateEntered datetime
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO Packages
    VALUES (@PPuid, @PSuid, @PTrackingNumber, @PDateEntered)
END
```

Comment: The error says "FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Packages_Shipments" which means in the Database there is a Key linking two tables together and Insert is violating the key restraint.  I would use SQL Server Management Studio and check log files under Management in the SQL Explorer to see if there is more info on this error.  Also check database table FK_Packages_Shipments contains a KEY for the table.

Comment: So the key linking two tables is psuid, which I am trying to pass from AddShipment.

Comment: Does script work if you call from SQL Server Management Studio?  See following : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64429717/sql-server-insert-into-two-tables-at-the-same-time-with-fk-to-each-other?force_isolation=true

Comment: Looks like ssuid is the PK for dbo.Shipments yet you're not using Identity and manually setting the key with a new GUID. Turn on Identity in Mgmt Studio and return that key from your procedure. Then you'll be able to use it as a FK in dbo.Packages.

Comment: @GHDevOps Do I only need to modify my sproc?

Comment: For Identity, set it in Management Studio under table design. You'll have to remove the parameter for ssuid in the AddShipment method. Just return the newly entered ssuid from your proc so you can use it in the other method.